# Scripting.FileSystemObject and ..lnk file

Tags: vbscript

I'm looping in a folder to get all files inside it

Scripting.FileSystemObject doesn't seem to see that a file named ..lnk exist

is there a way to fix that?

thanks

Comment: Could you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem that I made a mistake while creating my test environment, I created a folder instead of a file.

now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through a folder using WMI also seems to find *.lnk files. Try this example:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService. _
    ExecQuery("Select * from CIM_DataFile where Drive = 'C:' And Path = '\\Temp\\'")
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
Next
```

I hope this helps.

/ Frank